# Lucene regex v4

Tags: regex, lucene, kibana

I am trying to query on Kibana version 7.9.1 for a uuidv4. I disabled the KQL an now it looks like it is using lucene.
Example of a uuid v4:

2334e133-37a6-4039-8acd-b0a561b961b2

Now if I input :

`/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}/`

in the search bar I get hits, but as soon as I try to escape the hyphen like

`/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-/`

nothing shows up. I would like to use the full regular expression:

`[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}`

But I can't because of the hyphens.

Is there any other way to escape that pesky hyphen?
I am using elastic search 7.9.1 by the way

Comment: Do not escape hyphens, just use `[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}`

Comment: Hello Wiktor, thanks for commenting. I tried your regex and it didn't work, no hits unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that regex above won't work for you, but this was the best I could come up with given the context: `^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}[^\s\d\w!@#$%^&*()_+=\\\][{}|';:"\/.,<>?][0-9a-fA-F]{4}[^\s\d\w!@#$%^&*()_+=\\\][{}|';:"\/.,<>?][0-9a-fA-F]{4}[^\s\d\w!@#$%^&*()_+=\\\][{}|';:"\/.,<>?][0-9a-fA-F]{4}[^\s\d\w!@#$%^&*()_+=\\\][{}|';:"\/.,<>?][0-9a-fA-F]{12}$`

It basically is just replacing your "-" with a character not in range "[^...]" that I filled with almost everything except - and added a start character "^" and end character "$"

Again, not sure if lucene is just not using certain parts of regex, but try not escaping the -'s I know some programs will automatically escape symbols for you when using regex.

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately there were no hits.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following regex on lucene in the kibana discover option:

/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}/ AND /[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/ AND /[0-9a-fA-F]{12}/

Not pretty, but it works.